# How to return data from function that uses $.each()

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I try to `return` a value from a function that uses `$.each()` I get `undefined` instead of the value.  But when I return it directly from the function, it finds the value. Strange behaviour that I'm not familiar with how to resolve.

I made a fiddle here which is an example of this issue:
[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LPTRh/)

```
    function returneach() {
        $("b").each(function(i,v){
            if(i==3) { alert('should be: ' + i); return i; }
        });    
    }
    alert('but returns: ' + returneach()); // <- undefined
```

How do I get this working like it should?

Comment: `returneach` returns nothing. Try `return $.map(fn).toArray()`

Comment: your `returneach` function does not have a return statement, hence it does not return anything

Comment: ya - `return i` is specifying the return for the each loop, not the `returneach` function

Comment: @njzk2 `return i;` is clearly there.

Comment: What exactly do you want to return? Certainly not the `i` value.

Comment: @ZeeTee : it is in the function given to each, but it is not the return statement for `returneach`. You probably need to use `map`

Comment: But `i` (in my function) always returns a value, check the fiddle for a working example.

Comment: @ZeeTee: The `return` statements don't dismantle the entire call stack (thankfully). All JS functions have a default return value of `undefined`. This is returned when nothing else is specified.

Comment: Side note: `$.each()` is not the same thing as `$(selector).each()` - http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two nested functions here.

Your `return` inside the inner function will not cause the outer function to return.

Use a variable and return that variable:

```
function returneach() {
    var r;
    $("b").each(function(i,v){
        if(i==3) r = i;
    });
    return r; // This will either return 3 or undefined
}
```

Comment: you have a scope issue here, since 2 variables are named `v`

Comment: Sorry but -1 for the reason @njzk2 gave. This is getting too many votes considering it won't work as written.

Comment: Oops, my mistake. Updated.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can do something like this

```
function returneach() {
    var allTags$ = $("b");


    for(var i=0; i<allTags$.length; i++ ){
            if(i==3) { 
               return i;
            }
        }
}  
alert('but returns: ' + returneach());
```

Comment: This will be a *ReferenceError*.

Comment: @cookie now is it okay?

Comment: Yes,and in fact this will perform much faster than using `.each()`. +1 Though I guess it's not a direct answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Assign the index to a variable and then return it

```
function returneach() {
    var ret;
    $("b").each(function(i,v){
        if(i==3) { 
           ret = i;
        }
    });
    return ret;
}
alert('but returns: ' + returneach());
```

Answer (score 0):

A lot of times, iterating over a collection involves returning another collection or array. Here's an [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rwisch45/LPTRh/15/) showing that

```
function returneach() {
    var arr = [];
    $("b").each(function(i,v){
        if(i==3 || i == 2) { console.log('should be: ' + i); arr.push(i); }
    }); 

    return arr;
}
console.log('but returns: ' + returneach());
```

### Edit

Added function using `$.map()` as per advice from comments.

```
function returneachWithMap(){
    return $.map($('b'), function(i,v){
        if(v==3 || v == 2) { console.log('should be: ' + v); return v; };
    });    
}
console.log('but returns: ' + returneachWithMap());
```

Also, the title of the post doesn't reflect the code you are using. `$.each()` is not the same thing as `$(selector).each()`. From the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/):

> The $.each() function is not the same as $(selector).each(), which is
>   used to iterate, exclusively, over a jQuery object. The $.each()
>   function can be used to iterate over any collection, whether it is an
>   object or an array

Comment: If you're going to return a collection, you'd hopefully use `.map()` instead of `.each()`

Comment: Sort of. jQuery messes up `$.map` by swapping the parameters to the callback. It should be `function(v,i) {` for `$.map()`. If you used `$("b").map` then the parameters would be correct, but you'd need to chain `.toArray()` on the end. And you can skip the `arr` variable, and just do `return $.map(...`

Comment: ...oh, nevermind, you changed the parameter being returned instead of changing the names. Confusing, but technically correct.

Answer (score 0):

You have to return a value from `returneach()`

```
function returneach() {
    var retVal;
    $("b").each(function (i, v) {
        if (i == 3) {
            alert('should be: ' + i);
            retVal = i;
        }
    });
    return retVal;
}
alert('but returns: ' + returneach()); // <- undefined
```